# How to Prevent AJAX Spam Requests From Filling Up Database

Tags: javascript, ajax, spam

Simple scenario: I have a create album button that will insert album data into database.

- I deactivate the button while the request is processing and activate it on the callback.
- After the processing is done the user can click the button many times more and fill up the database with the same information, should I compare the album title, for example to avoid this?

If the button is deactivated on the client side using JavaScript couldn't I just change the code using firebug, for example, and get through this security measure?

Are any security measures on the client side secure (centering on the topic of disabling buttons or showing a `div` over the page to prevent another click)?

Comment: "Are any security measures on the client side secure" - Nope.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for handling this is generally called a nonce.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce

Put simply, each request has a value that assures it's only used once.  If there is nothing about the data to identify it as unique then you may need to build a scheme like that.

If the data itself is unique, create a unique key on your DB to prevent multiple inserts of the same data.